# Having trouble installing plotly with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, conda

I'm a novice, so please bear with me, but I am unable to install plotly using the snippets I've seen online so far:

`conda install -c plotly plotly=4.5.1`

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/win-64'

and

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly`

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly/win-64'

Please let me know if there is something I'm missing in installing this module. I'm completely at a loss. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want that particular version, or just the latest one? I just tried creating an environment containing plotly and it worked fine, and although I am using the conda-forge channel by default, it shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Are you able to install other packages? Do you use Anaconda's own command prompt or a windows one?

Comment: Hi AMC and Pascal,my apologies for the late response. Thank you both for responding to this post, but I figured out what happened; I had been trying this on my work computer on my company's network. I thought it might be interesting to try loading these packages on my home computer on a different network, and it worked just fine. I'm thinking my work has many firewalls as I'm in biotech and there are patient-sensitive data that we need to protect. Anyway, I believe this was the issue, so I'm going to ask IT to see if they can allow us to use this module for data analytics. Thanks again!